# Firefox: use system proxy settings, but where are these?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

Running Ubuntu 13.10, Firefox is configured to use the system proxy settings, but it seems it fails to pick them up. The computer is connected to the network, and it's possible to establish a connection with other browsers with the same username/password (so the problem is not here). I'd like to manually configure the proxy setting in Firefox, so want to know in what file they are.

Comment: Have you log out/in? I've configured proxys (in the system) before and they were picked up immediately.

Answer (score 3):

The system proxy settings should be stored as system-wide variables, present in /etc/environment :)

Everything is explained in more detail here https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio